# Platform specific UI adjustments in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms screen defined is the core library as below:

```
Content = new WebView
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Source = "https://google.com",
};
```

As a result for iOS the content is overlapped with the system tray (top bar with system icons). You can see them in left top corner. The issue is the same tray is separated from webview for Android and I couldn't just add static top margin. I need to do it on "per platform" basis. Is there a way to accomplish that?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible. You can use the `Device.OnPlatform()` method. Find out more in [the API docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.OnPlatform/).

Usage could be:

```
Device.OnPlatform (iOS: () => webView.Padding = new Thickness (0, 20, 0, 0));
```

`20` is the height of the statusbar.

There is also some documentation about [platform tweaks here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/platform-specifics/).

Comment: that works for me with the only correction - webview doesn't have padding, as instead I had to wrap it into Frame http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Frame/